# How can I export application with JavaFX so users without it can run the app

Tags: java, javafx

I have created simple app using Eclipse (JavaSE-1.8). I work on Windows and I have installed e(fx)clipse on my computer so I can easily use JavaFX and run the app. The problem is when I export the app to JAR file and run it on linux. I have to use `--module-path` and `--add-modules` to make it work with JavaFX. How can I export my App so users without JavaFX installed can run it without any problem?

I have tried:
- exporting Runnable JAR with option "Package required libraries into generated JAR"
- exporting by Maven with plugin `mvn jfx:jar`

Comment: have you tried setting the "target compapility" in eclipse to 1.8 ? And then build the jar again. 
This Problem occurs maybe because on Linux you have Java 11+ .

Comment: I have something like this [link](https://imgs.info/i/kVPlA) Is that what you mean? Or something else?